# How can i change the keyboard layout of blender back to english/default?

Tags: interface, shortcut, installation, windows

I'm new (actually just installed it a few hours ago), and wanted to access walk mode through <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>´</kbd> but i couldn't find the key Blender sees as <kbd>´</kbd> at first.

Neither the key left of <kbd>1</kbd> - which would be <kbd>´</kbd> in english keyboard layouts - nor the key left of <kbd>backspace</kbd> - which would be <kbd>´</kbd> on german layout - are the right ones.
Instead blender gets them as <kbd>\</kbd> (the left one) and <kbd>]</kbd> (the right one)

instead the <kbd>ö</kbd> key, which on english layout is the <kbd>;</kbd> key gets recognized as <kbd>´</kbd>, which i had to find out by trying out every possible key in the keybind menu.

TL;DR It's not any keyboard layout i know - neither english, nor german (which is the system setting) - and i can't use any hotkey combinations as of now, that don't just use letter keys.

i could theoretically set every keybind back to where it should be, but i don't think i want to do that for *every* keybind i might want to use in the future...

So how make i blender use the normal layout again?

Comment: Have you tried *restore to default settings*? Or is it the keyboard that is the problem.

Comment: As i just installed it i had not... i have now (just in case) and it's still the same @Nate_Sycro27

Comment: This is both a bit of an issue with the choice of shortcut selection and the blender key code interpretation. Might be worth leaving a comment on [T66607](https://developer.blender.org/T66607)